# Does DMZ direct traffic to its target even if initiated by another computer inside LAN?

Tags: router, nat, dmz

Suppose my setup looked like this:

1. Router 1 connects to the Internet (i.e. the modem).
2. Router 2's WAN port connects to a LAN port of Router 1.  (I.e. Router 2 is a 'router behind router' with its own subnet and DHCP.)
3. WILD (a computer) connects to a LAN port of Router 1.
4. GOOD, MILD and TAME (all computers) connect to LAN ports of Router 2.
5. Router 1 DMZs all incoming traffic to Router 2.
6. Router 2 port forwards to GOOD, MILD and TAME as needed.

**QUESTION**

Will element 5 (i.e. DMZ) prevent WILD from receiving 'answers' from the Internet?

I am sorry I don't know the technical word for 'answers.'

I have in mind, e.g.:

- WILD requests a Web page from CNN.com.  Will Router 1's DMZ send that Web page to Router 2 instead of WILD?
- An FTP client in WILD initiates an FTP session.  When the FTP server opens a data channel, will the DMZ send it to Router 2 instead of WILD?

**BACKGROUND**

As the name suggests, I would use WILD to visit Web sites and run executables which might contain malware.  I am placing Router 2 as a barrier (firewall) between WILD and the other computers.

I don't know if it matters, but WILD will actually be a virtual machine.  Assuming that WILD is hosted in TAME, TAME would have two NICs.  NIC 1 (connecting to Router 1) would be disabled in TAME and dedicated to WILD.  NIC 2 (connecting to Router 2) would be enabled in and used by TAME itself.

Neither Router 1 nor Router 2 has a vLAN feature.

This whole question assumes that I could not think of any better way to protect GOOD etc. from WILD.

The only other idea I have had is to place all computers in the same LAN, but use software firewall to isolate WILD.  But this seems to require that each of the other computers (including other VMs) must receive the necessary firewall settings, a lot more work than my proposed setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will element 5 (i.e. DMZ) prevent WILD from receiving 'answers' from the Internet?

### No.

It sounds like you misunderstand how a DMZ works. Placing a device in the DMZ does not cause Router 1 to redirect all traffic to that node. Instead you're simply putting the node in a different security zone where the normal behavior of the router works differently *for that device only*.

For example, traffic for devices in the DMZ zone are excluded from the router's firewall inspection.

Other devices behind Router 1's LAN interface will continue to behave normally. When WILD requests a web page, the router tracks the outbound connection so that when the response is received, it knows it needs to be send back to WILD.

Some routers (typically consumer models) also use the DMZ zone like a giant "forward all ports here" setting. As with all port-forwarding, this only affects *unsolicited, inbound* connections. Therefore, even with such a DMZ in place, inbound traffic that is part of a connection that was previously established by another host on the router's LAN will be sent to that node, not the DMZ'ed host.

---

For your purposes your setup seems reasonable. I've done similar two-router setups, though it can be challenging to get ports properly forwarded through such a configuration, usually because of routers that don't like being behind another NAT device. If it works for you, then all the better!

Comment: Thank you. But you seem to be describing a DMZ in a 'business' context (where, I am told, the DMZ host is separated from the rest of the LAN). I am speaking of the 'DMZ' feature in cheap routers, which is simply a way of forwarding all traffic to the designated machine. Would your answer still apply to this sense of 'DMZ'?

Comment: @Catomic Yes. Think about it: If putting a device in the DMZ forced Router 1 to send *all* traffic to it, no other device on the LAN side of the router could work. That would make having the router pointless, since you might as well connect that device directly to the Internet!